# Ajax undefined variable in php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My ajax function:

```
function get_employee_list(Parameter){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'resource/php/search_profile.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { var1 : Parameter},
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });return false;
}
```

My search_profile.php file:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['var1'];
?>
```

The response string says **var1** is undefined variable. Is there anything wrong in my ajax syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> contentType: false,
> processData: false
> ```

You've told jQuery not to convert the object to a suitably encoded format and not to set the content-type to tell PHP what that format is.

Consequently, PHP can't understand that data you are sending, so don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("resource/php/search_profile.php", {var1 : Parameter}, function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```